# How to remove "Google Search" icon in Launchpad permanently?

Tags: google-chrome, launchpad

Recently, I find this icon "Google Search" appears in my launchpad, I searched online and located this app in this "Chrome Apps" folder, deleted it. However, it appeared again the second day. This is really annoying. How can I delete it PERMANENTLY?

I don't even know how it happened, I've been using Chrome for a really long time, but this happened only a couple of days ago, didn't install any google related apps recently.

[image: Google Search icon]

[image: Chrome Apps folder]

Comment: If you delete it, then try to open, it should show a question mark over the icon. You should then be able to delete it just like deleting an app on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

#### Manual Deletion Required.

1. Go to your user (home) folder.
2. Click on Applications.
3. Right-click on the Chrome Apps folder and send it to the trash.
4. Empty your trash.

[image]

#### If above doesn't help:

From terminal try removing the following directory and empty trash:

rm -rf ~/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized

Comment: hi, is there any way to undo this operation? even installing chrome all over again didn't re-create the folder ~/Application/Chrome Apps.localized